# regex with multiple lists

Tags: python, regex

so I have multiple lists of various lengths. I am trying to search a corpus for strings containing any combination of items from these lists using regular expressions. I have no clue how to do this and have been searching for a while to discover a solution. If somebody could enlighten me on a technique, or point me to some documentation, that will be an acceptable answer as well.

### EXAMPLE

```
l1 = ["two","three",...,"twenty"]
l2 = ["cats","dogs","fish",...]
my_corpus = """
    I have three cats and two dogs, but I have no fish. 
    I don't care too much about being correct so matching
    the phrase dogs four is acceptable as well.
"""
```

Ideally I would like to match `"three cats"`,`"two dogs"`, and `"dogs four"` here.

It is important to note that the number of actual lists varies and that order really doesn't matter. But there are certainly too many possible permutations to hardcode this. If I were to even write a script that would create the regular expression with a string of `OR`, that string would end up being way too large (probably over 1 million characters).

### EDIT NOTES

- This must be possible with arbitrary numbers of lists. As mentioned, hard coding is not possible here because of the size of these lists. In reality I am using 6 lists, of size 2,10,10,100,1000,10000 respectively.
- This must be part of a regular expression. This is a subproblem that is part of a complicated parsing attempt that has already been completed in regex. Let the preexisting regex be `r'abc'` I would like to be able to turn that into r'a(?:b|solution)c' where a,b, and c are already completed regex.

  - It must match any arbitrary number of these words in a row

Let me know if there are any more questions.

Comment: About those six lists: Do I understand it correctly that there has to be exactly one word from each of those lists, in any order? If so, what do you mean with "match any arbitrary number of these words in a row"?

Comment: Any number of words from any of those lists. You could turn those lists into one set potentially. The only reason I don't in the example is because in future iterations of the project, the order will matter and the separation will be important

Comment: So, there could also be two words from `l1`, or three from `l2`? In this case, you should really just join all of them to one big disjunction (of 11122 words) and put a `+` behind that...

Answer (score 3):

does it have to be regex?

why not just iterate over words and check if any `N` adjacent ones are from the lists?

```
import re

l1 = ["two","three","four","twenty"]
l2 = ["cats","dogs","fish"]

my_corpus = """
    I have three cats and two dogs, but I have no fish.
    I don't care too much about being correct so matching
    the phrase dogs four is acceptable as well.
"""
non_alpha = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]')
words = [non_alpha.sub('',w) for w in my_corpus.split()]

sets = map(set,[l1,l2])
N = len(sets)
for i in range(len(words)-N):
    ws = words[i:i+N]

    # each word is in at least one set
    all_words = all(any(w in s for s in sets) for w in ws)

    # each set has at least one word
    all_sets = all(any(w in s for w in ws) for s in sets)

    # conditions broken into two for readability, but maybe should be used
    # inline for short circuiting, only important if number of sets is large
    if  all_words and all_sets:
        print ' '.join(ws)
```

output:

```
three cats
two dogs
dogs four
```

also, as commented by @tobias_k, using sets instead of lists will speed things up

Comment: Nice, but probably should make `l1` and `l2` sets to make this a bit faster.

Comment: You could also do `any(all(w in s for w,s in zip(ws, perm)) for perm in perms)` where `perms = permutations(sets)` instead of *each word in a set* and *each set has a word* ;)

Comment: @swenzel you're right, and it's shorter, but it's a much worse solution complexity wise - O(WS) vs O(WS!)

Comment: Your solution is O(WS^2) in worst case... but yeah, still better than O(WS!) :D

Comment: Okay then, another thought... since this is a rolling window like thing, you can keep information and don't need to check N times whether a certain word is in a set or not. Furthermore, if one isn't, you could jump ahead, since there is no way there will be a match within the next N steps.

Comment: @swenzel you're absolutely right, there many possible optimizations. this is just a POC, if it needs further optimizing, it would be an issue for a whole new question IMO.

Comment: Yes, the solution does require regex. I will edit to make this more clear. The gist is that this is a subsection of a much larger and complicated parsing project and I needed to insert this as an optional discovery in the preexisting regex

Comment: I have now added the edit making this more clear. If this is not possible I will most likely use what you have stated and adapt my other regex to python code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two big disjunctions from the lists, joining them with `|`, and use those in another disjunction in the regular expression.

```
p = r"({0}) ({1})|({1}) ({0})".format("|".join(l1), "|".join(l2))
print repr(p)
for m in re.finditer(p, my_corpus):
    print m.span(), repr(m.group())
```

Output (first the final regex, then the matches)

```
'(two|three|four) (cats|dogs|fish)|(cats|dogs|fish) (two|three|four)'
(12, 22) 'three cats'
(27, 35) 'two dogs'
(131, 140) 'dogs four'
```

I did some performance measurements (using just your lists and text, so this may not be representative for longer lists and texts), and it seems like the regex-approach is still about 8 times faster (~10µs) than the other solution matching all words and comparing them to the sets (~85µs), according to IPython's `%timeit`.

Comment: After OP's update: Okay, if you have 6 such lists with a total of 11122 words and 720 ways to arrange those lists, that regex would be a total of 8007840 words long... that's certainly not ideal, but I still can't think of another way to do this with a single regex.